# Robotframework - How to use an old chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Problem :
A specific app requires an older version of chrome to be used.
Example : Desired chrome version : 87.0.4280.88, but my system has 112.0.5615.137. System Chrome version cannot be downgraded.

Error when I try to execute a python script or a robot script that downloads and installs 87.0.4280.88.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 112.0.5615.137 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

Tools :

1. Python 3.11
2. WebDriverManager
3. Robotframework ( non ride )

Pseudo Code

1. Using WebDriverManager - download and install chromeversion XXX via python.
2. Use python script in robotframework as an exec to "use" recently download chrome.

Sample code that I use :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version="87.0.4280.88").install())
```

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${URL}            https://www.youtube.com/

*** Test Cases ***
Open YouTube Website
    Create WebDriver  Chrome  executable_path=${CURDIR}/chrome_driver_init.py
    Go To  ${URL}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Close Browser
```

Other attempts :

```
import os
import argparse
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run a Robot Framework test case with ChromeDriver 87")
parser.add_argument("test_case", help="Path to the Robot Framework test case file")
parser.add_argument("-r", "--results", help="Path to the directory where the test results will be saved")
parser.add_argument("--store-id", help="Store ID to be used in the test case")
parser.add_argument("--banner", help="Banner to be used in the test case")
parser.add_argument("--test-tag", help="Tag to be used for the test case")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Set the options for the ChromeDriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--ssl-protocol=TLSv1.2')
options.add_argument('--ssl-ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable as an environment variable
# driver_path = "./.cache/selenium/chromedriver/mac-arm64/87.0.4280.88"
# os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_path

# Start the ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version="87.0.4280.88").install(), options=options)

# Run the Robot Framework test
cmd_args = ["robot"]
if args.store_id:
    cmd_args.extend(["--variable", f"STORE_ID:{args.store_id}"])
if args.banner:
    cmd_args.extend(["--variable", f"BANNER:{args.banner}"])
if args.test_tag:
    cmd_args.extend(["--tag", args.test_tag])
if args.results:
    cmd_args.extend(["--outputdir", args.results])
cmd_args.append(args.test_case)
driver.close()
os.environ.pop("webdriver.chrome.driver")
exit_code = os.system(" ".join(cmd_args))
exit(exit_code)
```

Comment: not sure if it'll help but there is an environment variable you can set which tells Chromedriver not to check for major version.  In Java you'd do this: System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true");  For python, I think it's os.environ["webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck"] = true; ?  (or just set it manually on the machine it's running on...)  It may have been implemented in Selenium 4.x... not real sure but be sure to use Selenium 4.x if you aren't already and it doesn't work.  Not sure exactly when Chromedriver added support for this.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to have GoogleChrome and chromedriver. A quick search, returned this [site](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php), with downloads for different systems, like your MacOS.

You could try to have it installed in a separate location, different from the system's. Then use a script to change the PATH to find it first than the system's.

(just a comment: Why would an app need an old version of GoogleChrome? Why not use Safari or Firefox? That will give problems in the future, as you are already having.)

Comment: firefox is not allowed in our corp. and safari is not allowed in our linux servers.